# Confused setting price/ratio per token in solidity

Tags: solidity

I am trying to set the price ratio 1 token per 0.01 USDT

**Code**

```
uint256 public priceTokenPerDai = 10000000000000000;

function calculateAmountTokensPurchased(uint256 _amountPaid)
    public
    view
    returns (uint256)
{
    console.log("_amountPaid %s", _amountPaid);

    console.log("_____priceTokenPerDai %s", priceTokenPerDai);
    return priceTokenPerDai / _amountPaid;
}
```

**Ouput**

```
_amountPaid 10000000000000000000000000000000000

_____priceTokenPerDai 10000000000000000

BigNumber { value: "1" }

_amountPaid 1

_____priceTokenPerDai 10000000000000000
```

I'm a bit confused because decimals in solidity don't exist. I want to make a purchase of 1 cent for 1 token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well in solidity usually most tokens use 18 decimals (this isn't always true so is better to check it), so if you want to set the price of 1 per 0.1, the amount paid should also include the decimals if not you are "sending" 0.000000000000000001 tokens instead of 1